# Disable hashing of images on build of vue app

Tags: image, vue.js, webpack, hash, build

When you build a vue project, the assets in the dist folder get a fingerprint/chunkhash number for ex. "thumb.jpg" becomes "thumb.23423432.jpg" and the same applies to css files, js etc.

Is it possible to disable the hashing on build for only images files? If so, how do you do that within the vue.config.js file?

Comment: can you post your webpack.config.js?

Comment: My vue.config.js file is currently empty.

Comment: if you have your project in git, please share the url

Comment: I've posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57948894/955014

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to disable filenameHashing only for specific resources (images) in webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920923/is-there-a-way-to-disable-filenamehashing-only-for-specific-resources-images-i)

Answer (score 3):

You should try this one in vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/yourapp/',
    filenameHashing: false
}
```