# Is there a way to disable filenameHashing only for specific resources (images) in webpack?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, assets, staticresource

After building my website with `Vue.js 2.6.2` using `vue-cli`, I encountered a problem with static resources (images in this case). Webpack bundles them up in the `/img/` folder which is fine, but the images are given hashes like `image_demo.25d62d92.png` which is causing issues when trying to access those resources from an external source e.g. from another website.

There is an option for webpack to disable `filenameHashing` altogether, but that too great a sacrifice to not have the cache control for all the orher images on the website.

The desired solution is the option to have only some hand picked resources with their default names without the extra hash, while the other resources get the default `hash` for cache control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You will need to override the 'images' rule that `vue-cli` comes with.

`vue inspect --rule images` yields the following:

```js
$ vue inspect --rule images
/* config.module.rule('images') */
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)(\?.*)?$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 4096,
        fallback: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'img/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

(Protip: [`vue inspect`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config) is a useful tool for figuring out why things behave like they do when building with `vue-cli`)

### All images

`vue-cli` recommends [`webpack-chain`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) for 'advanced' configuration. I'm personally not a fan, but if you want to remove hashes for all images, you should probably modify the 'images' rule. Edit `vue.config.js` like so:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule("images")
      .use("url-loader")
      .loader("url-loader")
      .tap((options) => {
        options.fallback.options.name = "img/[name].[ext]"
        return options
      })
  }
  // ...
}
```

### Specific images

In my case I wanted to remove hashes only for a specific group of images with a unique prefix, so I added the following to `configureWebpack` in `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /unique-prefix-\d*\.png/, // <= modify this to suit your needs
          use: [
            {
              loader: "url-loader",
              options: {
                limit: 4096,
                fallback: {
                  loader: "file-loader",
                  options: {
                    name: "img/[name].[ext]", // <= note how the hash is removed
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  // ...
}
```

It could probably be done with `webpack-chain` as well, but I prefer the more vanilla Webpack config format.