# Vue3: remove hash from one specific filename

Tags: image, email, hash, vuejs3, filenames

I need to remove the hash from one specific png file. I use this resource outside of my website (in mail footer) and when the hash is changing, the image disappears. I know that [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920923/is-there-a-way-to-disable-filenamehashing-only-for-specific-resources-images-i) is a similar solution but it doesn't work for me.

Vue version: **3.2.13**

API: **Options**

I tried solution above with this code (vue.config.js):

```
configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /logo*\.png/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "url-loader",
              options: {
                limit: 4096,
                fallback: {
                  loader: "file-loader",
                  options: {
                    name: "img/[name].[ext]",
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  }
```

[and result looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxnvB.png) - it affect only this one file. Changing *test* atribute on `test: /logo-\d*\.png/` (like in solution) did nothing - didn't disable hash from filename but image appeared on page.

Also I tried `filenameHashing: false` but then github didn't allow my repo go to production (and I don't want to disable all hashing cause I care about caching). At last I tried change src in img tag on `:src="require('@/assets/img/logo.png')"` - but it didn't give any results (I mean hash wasn't removed).

**What I have right now?**

logo.########.png          (# - random string)

**What I expect?**

logo.png (or another possibility for working image in mail footer by copying img form my website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

I needed to change folder of my image from /src/assets to /public and use absolute path in img tag `<img src="/img/logo.png">` (folder: /public/img/).

Here is a link to [documentation note](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling) where is more detail about it.